# How do change my email back to from my son's email to mine on Google payment like Google store

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My son put his email into my Google purchase account and I cannot change it back to mine how do I do so

Comment: I have a brand brand new Samsung Verizon tablet simple to use but apparently not simple enough for me

Comment: Perhaps go to Settings > Account > Google ? From there delete his account or add yours.

Comment: Add your google account and change payment method on that.

Answer (score 0):

To change back to your payment method, open play store open the menu on the top left, press on the email address, and it should give you the option to switch. 
(That's if you added your account to your phone. If you didn't, follow the steps below and you'll see a way to add yours )

If you want to fully remove your son's account from your phone, go to phone settings>accounts>Google>[his email address]>three dots menu>remove account.